# Laravel - Redirect::action -> Unknown action

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

**route:**

```
Route::controller('account/pages','PagesController' );
Route::controller('account','AccountController' );    
Route::get('/', function() {
    return Redirect::to('account');
});
```

**PagesController:**

```
public function getGerente()
{
    return Redirect::action('GerenteController@getIndex');
}
```

**GerenteController:**

```
public function getIndex()
{
    return View::make('account/gerente/index');
}
```

**View:**

```
<a href="{{ URL::action('PagesController@getGerente') }}">Gerente</a>
```

But when click, return "Unknown action [GerenteController@getIndex]", how do i fix this??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have not defined a route for the GerenteController, the URL::action command does not know what to do. To fix:

```
//add to your routes file
Route::controller('gerente', 'GerenteController');
```